# Can't verify repository GPG signature even though key is installed

Tags: apt, gnupg, gnome-keyring

I'm facing a warning whenever I try to rur `apt update`:

```
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
```

This is a common issue, commonly solved by fetching the missing keys and installing them:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 23F3D4EA75716059
```

However, the key already exists locally and hasn't changed, so `apt-key` won't update it:

```
gpg: key 23F3D4EA75716059: "GitHub CLI <opensource+cli@github.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1
```

What would be next logical step? I've tried removing the key completely and adding it, but the issue persists.